# How to replace a broken block in a text file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a task to create a task that will get a data and put it in a log file. I have this sample text file, and it contains block/lines like this.

```
START OF SAMPLE

lines of sample
lines of sample
lines of sample    

END OF SAMPLE

START OF SAMPLE

lines of sample
lines of sample
lines of sample
linSTART OF SAMPLE

lines of sample
lines of sample
lines of sample

START OF SAMPLE

lines of sample
lines of sample
lines of sample

END OF SAMPLE
```

As you can see, there is a broken block in the sample.. I want to find that and replace it with something like this:

```
START OF SAMPLE

Corrupted SAMPLE

END OF SAMPLE
```

Even there is no END OF SAMPLE in that block, I want to have it like that..

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match all your samples which are valid. After that its up to you to do whatever you need to do with this data.

```
START OF SAMPLE(?:(?!START OF SAMPLE).)+?END OF SAMPLE
```

The following regex needs the DOTALL flag. for more data read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) on regular expressions in python.